Proxy plausible script in the nuxt2
I added a proxy to my Plausible script. The script was deployed successfully and the event was triggered, returning a success status, but the statistics were not updated.
In the nuxt config I add inside head:
script: [
      {
        src: '/js/script.js',
        defer: true,
        async: true,
        'data-domain': '****.***',
      },
    ],

****.**** - It's the name of my site
In proxy file:
require('dotenv').config()
export default {
  '/api/event': {
    target: 'https://plausible.io/api/event',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api/event': '' },
  },
  '/api': {
    target: process.env.NUXT_ENV_API_URL
      ? process.env.NUXT_ENV_API_URL
      : 'http://localhost:4000',
    pathRewrite: { '^/': '' },
  },
  '/js/script.js': {
    target: 'https://plausible.io/js/script.js',
    pathRewrite: { '^/js/script.js': '' },
  },
}

